# How to count the number of times all divs in a page are clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a php script where users click on the cells of a table to reveal their content. As part of my project, users are not allowed to click on more than 20 of the 100 cells. I would like to display on top of the page a countdown that will change each time they click on a div.

The page contains a table, and each cell of the table contains a DIV with an ID such as "a1_cont", "a2_cont", "a3_cont", ..., "a10_cont" for the first row. The second row is "b1_cont" to "b10_cont", and so on.

I would need the countdown to start at 20 and incrementally go down to 0 once the user has clicked 20 times. How would you advise me to do so?

Here is one row of the table. Don't yell at me about CSS, this is automatically generated by the mouselab web script, which is widely used in my field of research.

```
<TR style="background-color: green;">
<!--cell a0(tag:a0)-->
<TD align=center valign=middle><DIV ID="a0_cont" style="position: relative; height: 50px; width: 100px;"><DIV ID="a0_txt" STYLE="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 50px; width: 100px; clip: rect(0px 100px 50px 0px); z-index: 1;"><TABLE><TD ID="a0_td" align=center valign=center width=95 height=45 class="actTD">2 years</TD></TABLE></DIV><DIV ID="a0_box" STYLE="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 50px; width: 100px; clip: rect(0px 100px 50px 0px); z-index: 2;"><TABLE><TD ID="a0_tdbox" align=center valign=center width=95 height=45 class="boxTD">Years in Business</TD></TABLE></DIV><DIV ID="a0_img" STYLE="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 50px; width: 100px; z-index: 5;"><A HREF="javascript:void(0);" NAME="a0" onClick="ShowCont('a0',event)"><IMG NAME="a0" SRC="transp.gif" border=0 width=100 height=50></A></DIV></DIV></TD>
<!--end cell-->
<!--cell a1(tag:a1)-->
<TD align=center valign=middle><DIV ID="a1_cont" style="position: relative; height: 50px; width: 100px;"><DIV ID="a1_txt" STYLE="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 50px; width: 100px; clip: rect(0px 100px 50px 0px); z-index: 1;"><TABLE><TD ID="a1_td" align=center valign=center width=95 height=45 class="actTD">7 min</TD></TABLE></DIV><DIV ID="a1_box" STYLE="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 50px; width: 100px; clip: rect(0px 100px 50px 0px); z-index: 2;"><TABLE><TD ID="a1_tdbox" align=center valign=center width=95 height=45 class="boxTD">Call Handling Time</TD></TABLE></DIV><DIV ID="a1_img" STYLE="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 50px; width: 100px; z-index: 5;"><A HREF="javascript:void(0);" NAME="a1" onClick="ShowCont('a1',event)"><IMG NAME="a1" SRC="transp.gif" border=0 width=100 height=50></A></DIV></DIV></TD>
<!--end cell-->
<!--cell a2(tag:a2)-->
<TD align=center valign=middle><DIV ID="a2_cont" style="position: relative; height: 50px; width: 100px;"><DIV ID="a2_txt" STYLE="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 50px; width: 100px; clip: rect(0px 100px 50px 0px); z-index: 1;"><TABLE><TD ID="a2_td" align=center valign=center width=95 height=45 class="actTD">Very High</TD></TABLE></DIV><DIV ID="a2_box" STYLE="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 50px; width: 100px; clip: rect(0px 100px 50px 0px); z-index: 2;"><TABLE><TD ID="a2_tdbox" align=center valign=center width=95 height=45 class="boxTD">Representative Experience</TD></TABLE></DIV><DIV ID="a2_img" STYLE="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 50px; width: 100px; z-index: 5;"><A HREF="javascript:void(0);" NAME="a2" onClick="ShowCont('a2',event)"><IMG NAME="a2" SRC="transp.gif" border=0 width=100 height=50></A></DIV></DIV></TD>
<!--end cell-->
<!--cell a3(tag:a3)-->
<TD align=center valign=middle><DIV ID="a3_cont" style="position: relative; height: 50px; width: 100px;"><DIV ID="a3_txt" STYLE="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 50px; width: 100px; clip: rect(0px 100px 50px 0px); z-index: 1;"><TABLE><TD ID="a3_td" align=center valign=center width=95 height=45 class="actTD">$0.17</TD></TABLE></DIV><DIV ID="a3_box" STYLE="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 50px; width: 100px; clip: rect(0px 100px 50px 0px); z-index: 2;"><TABLE><TD ID="a3_tdbox" align=center valign=center width=95 height=45 class="boxTD">Cost per Minute</TD></TABLE></DIV><DIV ID="a3_img" STYLE="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 50px; width: 100px; z-index: 5;"><A HREF="javascript:void(0);" NAME="a3" onClick="ShowCont('a3',event)"><IMG NAME="a3" SRC="transp.gif" border=0 width=100 height=50></A></DIV></DIV></TD>
<!--end cell-->
<!--cell a4(tag:a4)-->
<TD align=center valign=middle><DIV ID="a4_cont" style="position: relative; height: 50px; width: 100px;"><DIV ID="a4_txt" STYLE="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 50px; width: 100px; clip: rect(0px 100px 50px 0px); z-index: 1;"><TABLE><TD ID="a4_td" align=center valign=center width=95 height=45 class="actTD">Strong Encryption</TD></TABLE></DIV><DIV ID="a4_box" STYLE="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 50px; width: 100px; clip: rect(0px 100px 50px 0px); z-index: 2;"><TABLE><TD ID="a4_tdbox" align=center valign=center width=95 height=45 class="boxTD">Customer Data Security</TD></TABLE></DIV><DIV ID="a4_img" STYLE="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 50px; width: 100px; z-index: 5;"><A HREF="javascript:void(0);" NAME="a4" onClick="ShowCont('a4',event)"><IMG NAME="a4" SRC="transp.gif" border=0 width=100 height=50></A></DIV></DIV></TD>
<!--end cell--><TD ID="btn_0" style="border-left-style: none; color: white;border-right-style: none; border-bottom-style: none;" align=center valign=middle><INPUT type="radio" name="mlchoice" value="btn1" onMouseOver="timefunction('mouseover','btn1','Alpha Co')" onClick="recChoice('onclick','btn1','Alpha Co')" onMouseOut="timefunction('mouseout','btn1','Alpha Co')">Alpha Co</TD>
</TR>
```

Comment: If you show us your actual table/div HTML, we could provide actual code to solve the problem.

Comment: if a div is clicked twice then?

Comment: How can I show the HTML? Should I post the whole thing here?

Comment: Post all relevant HTML here - paste it into your question and format it as code.  You should be able to know what is relevant and not (in other words, you don't usually paste in the whole page).

Comment: I added a row of the table to my question. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your actual HTML, this is the best guess for a selector that would match all the div elements.

```
(function() {
    var count = 20;
    var counted = {};
    $("div[id$='_cont']").click(function() {
        // only count this click if we haven't already counted this div
        if (!counted[this.id]) {
            counted[this.id] = true;
            --count;

            // update on screen counter here

            if (count == 0) {
                // max clicks reached
                // do whatever you want here
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

Note, this is written to only count a click on a given div once so multiple clicks in a single div will only count once.

Comment: This looks like a really cool code. It does not seem to work in my html though.

Comment: @user1029296 - As I already asked, please show us your HTML.  When you don't show your HTML, we have to just guess how to answer.  A good question shows all relevant HTML and JS.

Comment: I just added a some of the html code. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @user1029296 - I fixed one typo in my code (a missing quote mark).  It works in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/uLWKQ/. The demo also adds a red border when an item is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = 20;

$('div').click(function(){

     count = count - 1;

     if (count==0)
       alert('Youre done!')

});
```